# Frontend suddenly showing code

Tags: magento2, javascript, addtocart

We now have 'code' on our frontend. See image. Please advise

[image: frontend]

Comment: First...clear the cache. If that doesn't work....looks to me like you have translate inline enabled. Go to the backend Stores->Configuration->Advanced->Developer->Translate Inline and set `Enabled for Storefront` to `No`. Be careful. It might be set at website or store view level, not only for default settings.

Comment: Cleared, flushed cache a thousand times. It was in production mode when this happened without any now about. So no inline translation available there.

Answer (score 3):

So I think I know what was the issue.
- Sites were in development. Inline translation was on. 
- Developer at 'go live' did put sites on 'production' (but apparently did not switch inline translation off)
All still looked good from that time.

- Then we put a 'nl_NL.csv' file in the theme after a week and ran 
  php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy nl_NL -f and compiled

Then it all went wrong, sites go down.

After deleting all 'nl_NL.csv' from files sites came back alive but looking like origineal image.

Then we put sites back to 'development' mode. Then switched off inline translation.

Again, then we could force language to local language, complie, etc. Then back to 'production.

In short. Never put Magento 2 on production  mode when inline translation is still on.